# How can I get IDE autocomplete for PHPUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, phpstorm

I am using Symfony2, everything is installed, my tests work so good so far.

I'd like to get an autocompletion of PHPUnit's methods.

Symfony's  `WebTestCase` class extends from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` just like below:

```
abstract class WebTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

The parent class is highlighted as not existing although.

**How can I tell my IDE to use PHPUnit's library?**

I am using PHPStorm
PHPUnit is available by path `/Users/myUser/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add it as a library... in the project that you are editing add it to 'External Libraries'.

It should then be included.

Comment: FYI, to get to your project settings on Mac, click on PhpStorm -> Preferences, click PHP (under project settings), and then on the right you can add paths to your include path.

Comment: What about the .phar implementation of phpunit?

UPDATE: I got around this on my mac by just using a homebrew install of the lib.

Comment: You can just add the .phar file to the include path (you don't have to have the homebrew install as well).

Comment: With phpunit installed by homebrew, the path is /usr/local/opt/phpunit/libexec/  (this is a symlink so it will stay constant even with version changes)

Comment: As for those having a global composer install of phpUnit, add ~/.config/composer/vendor/phpunit to the path. 
And for those using PHPStorm 2016.2 checkout @piersb 's answer below

Comment: Here is how to do that : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-include-paths.html

Answer (score 17):

For me (Ubuntu 12.04) it was adding this folder as external library:

```
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 16):

For PHPStorm users, go to File -> Settings -> Project Settings ->PHP and add the path in there.

Comment: With phpunit installed by homebrew, the path is /usr/local/opt/phpunit/libexec/  (this is a symlink so it will stay constant even with version changes)

Answer (score 11):

PhpStorm 2016.2 introduces a feature which - in this case - is also a bug.

Autocompletion now no longer includes static methods as an option when in $this-> context. (https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/07/completion-changes-in-phpstorm/#more-10425)

As phpunit tests are defined as static methods but called via $this->, autocomplete for phpunit is now effectively broken.

They've rolled back this change for phpunit in the next EAP (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32530).

Workaround until the next stable release: Press CTRL-Space twice; this will then show static methods in the autocomplete field.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I was wondering about this and have searched a few times for bugs. The ctrl space works for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

You can add package `phpunit/phpunit` to the `require-dev` section of your composer.json file.

After running `composer install`, PHPStorm will know about the PHPUnit classes.

Comment: Could you add some details to your answer?

Comment: This worked nicely for me, adding the lib manually (as in other answers) didn't work out for me.

Comment: Maxim: Just add e.g. `"phpunit/phpunit": "^5.4.6"` to the `"require-dev"` section of your `composer.json` and run `composer update`.

Comment: Tried this on PhpStorm 2016.2. No joy. :(

Answer (score 2):

I have OSX, phpunit installed by homebrew and phpstorm 9.0

So how it works for me: open preferences or press cmd+, -> Languages&Frameworks -> PHP -> Include path -> add "/usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.7.6/libexec/"

Answer (score 0):

I have PHPStorm 2017.1.4 and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04. I already have phpunit.phar installed in my /usr/local/bin.

I will use ~/WORK/.. for the example paths but you should use the full path /home/myname/WORK/..

What I did is just go to a folder inside my home(like: ~/WORK/) and run:

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit
```

After composer was done downloading phpunit I added a new project include path to:

```
~/WORK/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src
```

Now I have all of the PHPUnit autocompletion, I can jump into PHPUnit's source code directly and I can keep the PHPUnit's code updated with composer. I also removed the phpunit.phar from /usr/local/bin and replaced it with a link to ~/WORK/vendor/bin/phpunit